# Spring Security testing Endpoint for user without specific role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I'm writing some integration tests for my Spring MVC Controller.

The controllers are secured by Spring Security.

This is the test class I currently have:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
    classes = GuiBackendApplication.class
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ConfigEditorControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockedMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "password", roles = {"admin"})
    public void adminsCanAccessRuntimeConfig() throws Exception {

        this.mockedMvc.perform(get("/my/custom/api"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This test class ensures that admins can access my endpoint. It works fine.

BUT what if I want to test if ONLY users with the admin role can access my endpoint?

I could write a test that uses @WithMockUsers with all the roles I currently have except the admin role. But that would me awful to maintain. I want my test to ensure that only users with the admin role can access my endpoint, regardless of any new roles.

I checked the Spring Reference Docs and didn't find anything about that. Is there a way to achieve that?

Something like this

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "password", roles = {"IS NOT admin"})
public void nonAdminsCannotAccessRuntimeConfig() throws Exception {

    this.mockedMvc.perform(get("/my/custom/api"))
        .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
}
```

Comment: Your test example seems correct to me. Or are you asking if Spring Security knows all your roles, and can generate a test that inverts the admin role into "all other roles available"? I don't know a way to do that, but I don't think you need to. Can you say more why that is required? Or perhaps I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg yeah, thats kinda what I want to achieve. Basically, I want to ensure, that at all times, only users with the admin role get responses from my endpoints. So basically, I would like that Spring checks whether the (mocked) user has the admin role, and if not, the controller should return a 401 status code. But there is probably no out of the bod solution for that (like the roles = {"IS NOT admin"} sketch I made in my initial post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security does not know what roles does your system define. So you have to tell it and test it one by one if you want to have 100% test coverage for all the available roles.

You can do it easily and in a maintenance way  by using JUnit 5 's `@ParameterizedTest` and configuring `MockMvc` with the `UserRequestPostProcessor` with different roles.

Something like :

```java
public class ConfigEditorControllerIntegrationTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource
    public void nonAdminsCannotAccessRuntimeConfig(String role) throws Exception {
        mockedMvc.perform(get("/my/custom/api")
                 .with(user("someUser").roles(role)))
                 .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    static List<String> nonAdminsCannotAccessRuntimeConfig() {
        return Roles.exclude("admin");
    }
}
```

And create a class to maintain all the available roles :

```java
public class Roles {

    public static List<String> all() {
        return List.of("admin", "hr", "developer" , "accountant" , .... , "devops");
    }

    public static List<String> exclude(String excludeRole) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(all());
        result.remove(excludeRole);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring wouldn't have to know all my roles. It just has to know at the time of the test whether the user has the admin role or not. But thanks for the proposed solution, it may be a neat workaround for my problem :)